# R decision tree hangs for hours

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am using R and I am training a decision tree. There are 10 columns with features and 1170 observations. I open an Excel file, transform it into a data frame and train the tree. Of course, a column with classification is separate from columns with features.

It has been 20 hours since I run the program and it still did not finish calculations. When I limit the number of observations to 10, decision tree is ready in seconds.

The problem is that then there is an error when I try to use this decision tree trained on 10 observations to predict values for the entire data sample (1170 observations).

An error appears that says that values of variables go far beyond values used in training of the tree.

I am almost certain that it is me who made some mistake, I just cannot pinpoint what it is.

```
train_cols <- df3[,c(18,30, 42, 54, 186, 222, 258, 270, 294, 318)]
tree_model <- rpart(df3[1:1100, 2] ~ ., data = train_cols[1:1100,], method = "class",control = rpart.control(cp = 0.01, minsplit = 2, maxdepth = 5, na.action = "na.pass"))
pred <- predict(tree_model, train_cols, type = "class", na.action=na.omit)
```

Observations are classified as belonging to 4 possible classes (from 0 to 4). I want the decision tree to predict to which class observations belong to.

There are many `NA`s in the data frame, perhaps this might be causing problems. On ther other side, decision trees are quite good with dealing with missing values.

Distribution of dependent variable is as follows:
`0->135 obs`
`1->12 obs`
`2->924 obs`
`3->98 obs`

Comment: In general you might want to rely on a framework to have a standardized interface and some other convenience to fit your models. mlr3 is such a framework :) https://github.com/mlr-org

Comment: Since you're using classification, how many classes are there? In other words, how many unique values are there as the outcome variable (AKA dependent variable)? Of those unique dependent variables, how many of each do you have? When you split the data, did you validate that you had a sufficient number of each unique class? Can you add `table(outcome_variable)` for your training data to your question? (It can be a big issue, but it's easy to rule out.)